# After upgrading, why isn't my Meteor app starting anymore?

Tags: meteor, upgrade, meteorite

In order to update all the meteor packages in my app, I feed in the command `meteor update --all-packages`. Many packages seem to now be updated to their latest versions, BUT now when I try to start my app using `meteor --port 8000`, the firing up of the app seems to stall in the `Starting your app         /` process indefinitely ...meaning my app never actually fires up anymore!

Find below an image illustrating my experience:

[image]

Does anyone know why this is happening and perhaps provide a solution to the issue? Looking forward to your help!

Find below further details.

Following is the reaction after I fed in: `meteor update --all-packages`

```
Changes to your project's package version selections from updating the release:


accounts-base              upgraded from 1.3.1 to 1.4.3
accounts-facebook          upgraded from 1.2.1 to 1.3.2
accounts-google            upgraded from 1.2.0 to 1.3.2
accounts-oauth             upgraded from 1.1.15 to 1.1.16
accounts-password          upgraded from 1.4.0 to 1.5.1
accounts-ui                upgraded from 1.1.9 to 1.3.1
accounts-ui-unstyled       upgraded from 1.2.1 to 1.4.1
allow-deny                 upgraded from 1.0.6 to 1.1.0
autoupdate                 upgraded from 1.3.12 to 1.5.0
babel-compiler*            upgraded from 6.19.4 to 7.2.0
babel-runtime              upgraded from 1.0.1 to 1.3.0
base64                     upgraded from 1.0.10 to 1.0.11
binary-heap                upgraded from 1.0.10 to 1.0.11
blaze                      upgraded from 2.3.2 to 2.3.3
boilerplate-generator      upgraded from 1.1.1 to 1.6.0
caching-compiler           upgraded from 1.1.9 to 1.2.0
callback-hook              upgraded from 1.0.10 to 1.1.0
check                      upgraded from 1.2.5 to 1.3.1
coffeescript               downgraded from 1.12.6_1 to 1.0.17
ddp                        upgraded from 1.3.0 to 1.4.0
ddp-client                 upgraded from 2.0.0 to 2.3.3
ddp-common                 upgraded from 1.2.9 to 1.4.0
ddp-server                 upgraded from 2.0.0 to 2.2.0
diff-sequence              upgraded from 1.0.7 to 1.1.0
dynamic-import             upgraded from 0.1.1 to 0.5.0
ecmascript                 upgraded from 0.8.2 to 0.12.0
ecmascript-runtime         upgraded from 0.4.1 to 0.7.0
ecmascript-runtime-client  upgraded from 0.4.3 to 0.8.0
ecmascript-runtime-server  upgraded from 0.4.1 to 0.7.1
ejson                      upgraded from 1.0.13 to 1.1.0
es5-shim                   upgraded from 4.6.15 to 4.8.0
facebook-config-ui         upgraded from 1.0.1 to 1.0.2
facebook-oauth             upgraded from 1.3.2 to 1.5.0
fastclick                  removed from your project
fetch                      added, version 0.1.0
google-config-ui           upgraded from 1.0.0 to 1.0.1
google-oauth               upgraded from 1.2.5 to 1.2.6
http                       upgraded from 1.2.12 to 1.4.1
id-map                     upgraded from 1.0.9 to 1.1.0
inter-process-messaging    added, version 0.1.0
less                       upgraded from 2.7.9 to 2.8.0
localstorage               upgraded from 1.1.1 to 1.2.0
logging                    upgraded from 1.1.17 to 1.1.20
meteor                     upgraded from 1.7.0 to 1.9.2
meteor-base                upgraded from 1.1.0 to 1.4.0
minifier-css               upgraded from 1.2.16 to 1.4.0
minifier-js                upgraded from 2.1.1 to 2.4.0
minimongo                  upgraded from 1.2.1 to 1.4.5
mobile-experience          upgraded from 1.0.4 to 1.0.5
modern-browsers            added, version 0.1.2
modules                    upgraded from 0.9.2 to 0.13.0
modules-runtime            upgraded from 0.8.0 to 0.10.2
mongo                      upgraded from 1.1.22 to 1.6.0
mongo-decimal              added, version 0.1.0
mongo-dev-server           added, version 1.1.0
mongo-id                   upgraded from 1.0.6 to 1.0.7
npm-mongo*                 upgraded from 2.2.30 to 3.1.1
oauth                      upgraded from 1.1.13 to 1.2.3
oauth2                     upgraded from 1.1.11 to 1.2.1
ordered-dict               upgraded from 1.0.9 to 1.1.0
promise                    upgraded from 0.8.9 to 0.11.1
random                     upgraded from 1.0.10 to 1.1.0
rate-limit                 upgraded from 1.0.8 to 1.0.9
reactive-dict              upgraded from 1.1.9 to 1.2.1
reload                     upgraded from 1.1.11 to 1.2.0
retry                      upgraded from 1.0.9 to 1.1.0
routepolicy                upgraded from 1.0.12 to 1.1.0
session                    upgraded from 1.1.7 to 1.1.8
shell-server               upgraded from 0.2.4 to 0.4.0
socket-stream-client       added, version 0.2.2
srp                        upgraded from 1.0.10 to 1.0.12
standard-minifier-css      upgraded from 1.3.4 to 1.5.0
standard-minifier-js       upgraded from 2.1.1 to 2.4.0
tracker                    upgraded from 1.1.3 to 1.2.0
url                        upgraded from 1.1.0 to 1.2.0
webapp                     upgraded from 1.3.17 to 1.7.0



* These packages have been updated to new versions that are not backwards
compatible.
escrow: updated to Meteor 1.8.                

-- Notice --                                  

1.7: The underscore package has been removed as a dependency of all packages in
     meteor-base. Since some apps may have been using underscore through this
     dependency without having it listed in their .meteor/packages files, it
     has been added automatically. If your app is not using underscore, then
     you can safely remove it using 'meteor remove underscore'.

Changes to your project's package version selections from updating package
versions:

caching-html-compiler  upgraded from 1.1.2 to 1.1.3
iron:url               upgraded from 1.0.11 to 1.1.0
jquery                 upgraded from 1.11.10 to 1.11.11
mizzao:timesync        upgraded from 0.3.4 to 0.5.0
momentjs:moment        upgraded from 2.18.1 to 2.22.2
spacebars-compiler     upgraded from 1.1.2 to 1.1.3
standard-minifier-css  upgraded from 1.5.0 to 1.5.1
templating-compiler    upgraded from 1.3.2 to 1.3.3

The following top-level dependencies were not updated to the very latest
version available:
 * iron:router 1.1.1 (1.1.2 is available)     

Newer versions of the following indirect dependencies are available:
 * coffeescript 1.0.17 (2.3.1_2 is available) 
These versions may not be compatible with your project.
To update one or more of these packages to their latest
compatible versions, pass their names to `meteor update`,
or just run `meteor update --all-packages`.
```

The package.json content is

```
{
  'name': 'Mellrose',
  'private': true,
  'scripts': { 
    'start': 'meteor run' 
  },
  'dependencies': {
      '@babel/runtime': '^7.1.2',
      'africastalking': '0.0.10',
      'babel-runtime': '^6.20.0',
      'bcrypt': '^1.0.3',
      'meteor-node-stubs': '~0.2.4'
  }
}
```

The current Meteor version is: `Meteor 1.8`

Ubuntu version is `Ubuntu 16.04 LTS`

Please help!

Comment: did you update babel? (meteor npm install @babel/runtime@latest).  if so, can you provide the output with run --verbose

Comment: @DavidK. Am not too sure yet, but it seems like a simple `meteor reset` fixed the issue

Comment: same, it works the first time i do a meteor reset but stuck at the second time....

Comment: @Dayd I am experiencing the exact same issue. Kindly let me know if you've figured out how to resolve the issue

Comment: Try to uninstall Meteor and reinstall with chocolatey, it works for me

Comment: @Dayd How does this Chocolatey work? How do I install using chocolatey? Any further documentation would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you under Windows ? https://www.meteor.com/install

Comment: @Dayd no I am using Ubuntu

Comment: Could you please add the content of your `packages` list, the `package.json` content, `versions` content, Meteor `release` version and Ubuntu version so I can try to replicate your issue.

Comment: @Jankapunkt The `package.json` content is `{
  "name": "Mellrose",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "meteor run"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.1.2",
    "africastalking": "0.0.10",
    "babel-runtime": "^6.20.0",
    "bcrypt": "^1.0.3",
    "meteor-node-stubs": "~0.2.4"
  }
}
` The current Meteor version is: `Meteor 1.8` and my Ubuntu version is `Ubuntu 16.04 LTS`. Also the package list is in the original post

Comment: @SirBT I mean the packages list exactly like in your `.meteor/packages` file so I can copy it 1-on-1 and paste it in my reproduction project. Otherwise it will take ages to manually reproduce which packages you have installed explicitly and which of them where added implicitly. The changes listed by `--update-all-packages` also shows updated packages that are peer dependencies of the ones in the list.

Comment: @Jankapunkt thanks for the clarification, however there isn't a folder in my project root called `packages`. Perhaps you can demonstrate how to access this folder along with its contents?

Comment: It is located there `projectroot/.meteor/packages`

Comment: @Jankapunkt located in the project root, when I write teh command `cd packages` I get: `bash: cd: packages: No such file or directory`

Comment: located in the project root `cd ./.meteor/ && cat packages`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182931/discussion-between-sirbt-and-jankapunkt).

Comment: Do you have heavy code under Meteor.startup() ?